# Optimization of simple functions containing loops or recursion

Tags: scala, loops, recursion, optimization

I'm working on a problem in **codewars** and I got my code to work, but it times out. I tried both recursion and loops but both timeout and calculate in similar amounts of time on the simple tests. I don't know how to optimize further either within my novice ability.

Recursion:

```
def recursive(p: Int, n: Int, l: List[Int], x: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if (n == p)
    x
  else
    recursive(p, n + 1, l, (l.drop(p - n - 1).sum :: x))
}

def partsSums(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val a = l.length
  recursive(a, 0, l, List(0))
}
```

Loop:

```
def partsSums(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val g = l.length
  var x = List(0)
  var n = 0
  while (n != g) {
    x = (l.drop(g - n - 1).sum) :: x
    n += 1
  }
  x
}
```

Comment: Is `l.scanRight(0)(_ + _)` enough?

Comment: Without a link to the challenge, or a description thereof, it's rather difficult to assess what you're trying to achieve but, that being said, 9 times out of 10, when your code times out you probably can't optimize your way out of it. More often than not you have to rethink your algorithm.

Comment: @esse how do I get stack to acknowledge that you solved it?

Comment: @MatthewWyatt I added an answer, you can accept it if works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your two functions time out is both their time complexities are O(n^2). Actually only O(n) is needed. A simple solution as following:

```
l.scanRight(0)(_ + _)
```

If you prefer to a solution with tail recursion, this one should work:

```
def rcumsum(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
   def imp(ys: List[Int], cum: List[Int], acc: Int): List[Int] = ys match {
     case Nil   => cum
     case y::rs => imp(rs, (y+acc)::cum, y+acc)
   }
   imp(xs.reverse, List(0), 0)
 }
```